# How to stop a website from referring to it's app/play store?

Tags: chrome-for-android, screen-resolution, video-streaming, amazon-video

I'm trying to use Prime Video as a desktop website on Chrome (Galaxy S9+). The PrimeVideo app would not let me view any better than 720p, which is ridiculous. But the website always refers me back to the app or the play store's download page.

Is there a way around it, or any other way to view at least 1080p on my S9+?

Answer (score 3):

You can open the website in incognito mode.

It will not redirect you to the Play Store

Comment: It would not make a difference by using incognito mode. Regardless, I'd have to log into my account even during incognito mode. Thanks for your response though.